# Create auto-closing Sheets overlay to provide feedback without error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Currently I'm using an alert window to give feedback to the user how many sheets have been exported and where. I noticed from Google Cloud Platform StackDriver logs that I got the error "Timed out waiting for user response" from that window, which means that some users just don't press the okay button. I can totally understand that, since this is information I want to show for a limited time.

[image: Google alert window]

So I'm wondering: Is there any best practise from Google how to show a simple popup that vanishes after a certain time? Maybe something similar looking to the Google working bubble at the bottom:
[image: Google Sheets working Bubble]

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether this is useful for your situation, for example, how about using ``toast(msg, title, timeoutSeconds)``? You can see the detail information at [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#toastmsg-title-timeoutseconds).

Comment: @Tanaike Yes, that's perfect (even togh it looks quite ugly). I actually went with the timeless version, since it is still possible to use the spreadsheet with this small popup :)

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad if that was useful for your situation.

Answer (score 0):

A simple popover can be found in the method [toast(msg, title)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#toastmsg-title). Toast also supports a timed message [toast(msg, title, timeoutSeconds)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#toastmsg-title-timeoutseconds)

[image: Toast with just the title and message]